# Plot of Sum of Factors of a number that are less than it

Tags: number-theory

[Abundant Numbers on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number)

I plotted the sum of factors of numbers upto 1000 and saw a linear pattern in the plot - as if the plot is bounded above and below by linear bounds. Can anyone explain this?

This is the plot: [image: x= n<=1000; y= sum of factors of x less than x].
[Here](http://ideone.com/7QqY0D) is the code for this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower line is $y=x+1$ coming from the primes.  The upper edge is not a straight line.  $\frac yx$ eventually rises above any value you like.  You could look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17742/sum-of-the-factors-of-any-natural-number)